# Arduino POST data

Tags: http, post, get, arduino, request

Is there a way to POST data to a website with an arduino uno with no shield?

And if there is a way to do this. How would I achieve this.

I've found this code on stackoverflow but I dont know if this is working without shield and I also don't know if I can get the output of the website to display in the serial monitor?

```
 IPAddress server(10,0,0,138);
 String PostData = "someDataToPost";

 if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    client.println("POST /Api/AddParking/3 HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: 10.0.0.138");
    client.println("User-Agent: Arduino/1.0");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.println(PostData.length());
    client.println();
    client.println(PostData);
  }
```

Comment: Does your arduino have ethernet or wifi built in?

Comment: You need to get that string to a device or machine that has internet access, most likely by serial port.  Though it's hard to imagine a practical use for such a setup.

Comment: @kicken No it doesn't have ethernet or wifi built in

Comment: The `UNO` has no built in networking capabilities so if you want to do this, you will need to pickup a shield for it. Or alternatively, you can look at the boards at: https://www.arduino.cc/boards and choose one with ethernet which suits your needs from therer.